# How to show multiple location markers on map using Places API in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

Here I am making an android app where I am retrieving the latitude and longitude from the JSON file. and showing markers on google map. I want to show all the nearby hospitals on my map within a 1km radius. I have also enabled the APIs. **The map shows the JSON file URL but doesn't show the markers on google map**. I am stuck at this point and couldn't figure out what is the actual problem with the code.
Kindly please help me with this error or any possible mistake I have done. any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

here is my JSON file. This file included many hospitals, so I have added only 1 hospital data from my JSON file

```
"results" : [
      {
         "business_status" : "OPERATIONAL",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.6327965,
               "lng" : 73.06251920000001
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.6341501802915,
                  "lng" : 73.0637985802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.63145221970851,
                  "lng" : 73.0611006197085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/doctor-71.png",
         "id" : "3fa0f9e5050e90cd8a160b8dbbf731f0759ea5fa",
         "name" : "Healers Center Hospital",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 4128,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105384437691919760909\"\u003eDr Sohail Malik\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAtd17x9IwXeQOQXbhagxoEVPCi6SutYfqz55JKAqyUGtE_Xj7nUSITFnOK2_tISls7rz7_oqikG4ffDWbqVKzGw15g1FjEDMfvJQnhWI_9kOC1dl-O3Qwc_aKA-7YvndyEhAfVnOscXsK0mTNiIBSYJTyGhSiP9tR_D1Rb-dEPAvvtgP4CjZmVQ",
               "width" : 2322
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJiZ8Z7-CU3zgRaH9qFQpj_xA",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "J3M7+42 Rawalpindi, Pakistan",
            "global_code" : "8J5MJ3M7+42"
         },
         "rating" : 4.4,
         "reference" : "ChIJiZ8Z7-CU3zgRaH9qFQpj_xA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "health", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 7,
         "vicinity" : "Saidpur Road, Rawalpindi"
      },
```

Here is my GetNearbyPlacesData file:

```
class GetNearbyPlacesData : AsyncTask<Any?, String, String>() {
    private var googlePlacesData: String? = null
    private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null
    private var url: String? = null

    override fun doInBackground(vararg objects: Any?): String? {
        mMap = (objects.first() as Array<Object>)[0] as GoogleMap
        url = (objects.first() as Array<Object>)[1].toString()

        val downloadURL = DownloadUrl()
        try{
            googlePlacesData = downloadURL.readUrl(url!!)

        } catch (e: IOException)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return googlePlacesData
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(s: String ) {

        val nearbyPlaceList: List<HashMap<String, String>>
        val parser = DataParser()
        nearbyPlaceList = parser.parse(s)
        showNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlaceList)

        Log.d("nearby places data", nearbyPlaceList.toString());
    }


    private fun showNearbyPlaces(nearbyplaces: List<java.util.HashMap<String, String>>)
    {
        for (i in 0 until nearbyplaces.size) {
            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
            val googlePlace = nearbyplaces[i]

            val PlaceName = googlePlace["place_name"]
            val vicinity = googlePlace["vicinity"]
            val lat = googlePlace["lat"]!!.toDouble()
            val lng = googlePlace["lng"]!!.toDouble()

            val latLng = LatLng(lat, lng)
            markerOptions.position(latLng)
            markerOptions.title("$PlaceName : $vicinity")
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))


            mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)
            mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
            mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(12f))

        }
        }
}
```

Here is my DataParser class:

```
class DataParser {

    private fun getPlace(googlePlaceJson:JSONObject):HashMap<String,String>{

        val googlePlacesMap = HashMap<String,String>()
        var placeName = "--NA--"
        var vicinity = "--NA--"
        var latitude = ""
        var longitude = ""
        var reference = ""

        try {
            if(!googlePlaceJson.isNull("name")) {
                placeName = googlePlaceJson.getString("name")
            }
            if(!googlePlaceJson.isNull("vicinity")) {
                vicinity = googlePlaceJson.getString("vicinity")
            }
            latitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat")
            longitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng")
            reference = googlePlaceJson.getString("reference")

            googlePlacesMap["place_name"] = placeName
            googlePlacesMap.put("vicinity", vicinity)
            googlePlacesMap.put("lat", latitude)
            googlePlacesMap.put("lng", longitude)
            googlePlacesMap.put("reference", reference)


            Log.d("Place Name", placeName)
        }
        catch (e: IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return googlePlacesMap
    }

    private fun getPlaces(jsonArray: JSONArray):List<HashMap<String,String>>{

        val count:Int = jsonArray.length()
        val placesList = ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>()
        var placeMap: HashMap<String,String>

        for (i in 0 until count){
            try {
                placeMap = getPlace(jsonArray.get(i) as JSONObject)
                placesList.add(placeMap)
            }
            catch (e:JSONException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return placesList
    }

    fun parse(jsonData: String):List<HashMap<String,String>>{

        var jsonArray:JSONArray? = null
        val jsonObject:JSONObject

        try{
            jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonData)
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results")
        }
        catch (e:JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return getPlaces(jsonArray!!)
    }
```

Here is my downloadUrl class:

```
class DownloadUrl {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun readUrl(myUrl: String): String {

        var data = ""
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null

        try {
            val url = URL(myUrl)
            urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConnection.connect()

            inputStream = urlConnection.inputStream
            val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream!!))
            val sb = StringBuffer()

            val line = ""
            while ((line == br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line)

            data = sb.toString()
            br.close()
        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            inputStream!!.close()
            urlConnection!!.disconnect()
        }
        Log.d("DownloadURL", "Returning data= $data")
        return data
    }
    }
```

Here is my main file where I have used these all three classes to show the markers on Google Map:
I didn't add the full code for this activity and I have only shown code related to the three classes shown above. the remaining part I have not included here is of my current location and permission requests

```
class SearchBloodBanks : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient
    private var currentLatitude: Double = 0.0
    private var currentLongitude: Double = 0.0
    private lateinit var myLocation: Location
    private val REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLIER_PERMISSION = 1
    private val REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS = 2
    var PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 1000
    private var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
    private var currentLocationMarker: Marker? = null

 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
        mMap.uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)
        mMap.uiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(true)
    }


    private fun getUrl(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, nearbyPlace: String ): String? {

        val googlePlaceUrl = StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?")
        googlePlaceUrl.append("location=").append(latitude).append(",").append(longitude)
        googlePlaceUrl.append("&radius=").append(PROXIMITY_RADIUS)
        googlePlaceUrl.append("&type=$nearbyPlace")
        googlePlaceUrl.append("&sensor=true")
        googlePlaceUrl.append("&key=" + resources.getString(R.string.places_api_key))

        Log.d("NearbyHospitalActivity", "url = $googlePlaceUrl")
        return googlePlaceUrl.toString()
    }

 override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        myLocation = location

        currentLatitude = location.latitude
        currentLongitude = location.longitude

        currentLocationMarker?.remove()


        val latLng = LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
        markerOptions.position(latLng)
        markerOptions.title("Current Location")
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))

        currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(0F))

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates( mGoogleApiClient, this)

    }

  private fun ShowHospitals(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {

        val dataTransfer = arrayOfNulls<Any>(2)
        val getNearbyPlacesData = GetNearbyPlacesData()
        val url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, "hospital")
        dataTransfer[0] = mMap
        dataTransfer[1] = url
        getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Showing Nearby Hospitals", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Gson() library to parse your json document, it would make the code much easier to read and also have you tried debugging the data you are passing into showNearbyPlaces to ensure that you have the right data in it.

Comment: Another advice would be for you to limit the use of !! in your code it tends to cause an exception incase the variable is null.

Comment: @Fadman actually i don't know how to convert json to gson. and i haven't debugged it yet. because the URL I am receiving for nearby places during runtime
and the second thing is if i don't use !! it gives me error :(
Also i have seen many videos related to nearby places and used the same code with a little bit of modification. still they are getting the results and i am not!